# Fill an object dynamically in react with values from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I'm trying to fill an object with values that I'm getting from an array of objects but it's not working as expected.

This is a simplified code example

https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-nobel-c7xdb?file=/src/App.js

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [fieldsValues, setFieldsValues] = useState({});
  const items = [{ value: "a" }, { value: "b" }, { value: "c" }];

  useEffect(() => {
    items.map((item, index) => {
      return setFieldsValues({
        ...fieldsValues,
        [index]: item.value
      });
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2> {` fieldsValues = ${JSON.stringify(fieldsValues)}`} </h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I want the fieldsValues to return this:

```
{
  0: "a",
  1: "b",
  2: "c"
}
```

What I'm getting now:

```
fieldsValues = {"2":"c"}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You fix it by doing this

```
useEffect(() => {
  items.map((item, index) => {
    return setFieldsValues((prev) => ({
      ...prev,
      [index]: item.value,
    }));
  });
}, []);
```

Better way of doing this is

```
useEffect(() => {
  const data = items.reduce(
    (prev, item, index) => ({ ...prev, [index]: item.value }),
    {}
  );

  setFieldsValues((prev) => ({ ...prev, ...data }));
}, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

To create the object map the array to `[index, value]` pairs, and convert to an object with `Object.fromEntries()`:

```js
const items = [{ value: "a" }, { value: "b" }, { value: "c" }];

const result = Object.fromEntries(items.map(({ value }, index) => [index, value]))

console.log(result)
```

However, the way you are using the array, and then need to set the state doesn't actually makes sense in the react context.

If the array is a prop, you should add it to `useEffect` as a dependency:

```
const arrToObj = items => Object.fromEntries(items.map(({ value }, index) => [index, value]))

export default function App({ items }) {
  const [fieldsValues, setFieldsValues] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    setState(() => arrToObj(items))
  }, [items]);
  
  ...
```

If it's a static array, set it as the initial value of `setState`:

```
const arrToObj = items => Object.fromEntries(items.map(({ value }, index) => [index, value]))

const items = [{ value: "a" }, { value: "b" }, { value: "c" }];
    
export default function App({ items }) {
  const [fieldsValues, setFieldsValues] = useState(() => arrToObj(items));
      
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

By your way It would be like this

```
  useEffect(() => {
    let test={}
    items.map((item, index) => {
      return setFieldsValues((prev)=>{
        return {
        ...prev,
        [index]: item.value
      }
      });
    });
  }, []);
```